# Programming Coded UI Tests from Scratch

Tags: selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests

I am looking to write automated tests in VSTS 2010 using Coded UI.

When i searched for some resources i found most of them about recording tests.

What i want to do is write tests like what we write in Selenium / Watin.

Are there any resources that would help me with api reference?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: ranomore is right, I agree that this is definitely a valid question!  The api reference can be found on MSDN, as well as a few articles there, however that won't be a whole lot of help.  I suggest you play around with the recordings for a little while.  I currently do most of my coded ui tests manually (without recordings) but I learned the best ways to do this by seeing the code that was generated from recordings.